# How to upgrade "actionview" in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, gemfile

I want to upgrade actionview version to " 5.2.4, >= 5.2.4.2, >= 6.0.2.2 ", I tried "bundle update actionview" but still It wasn't upgraded.[Please Find the attached screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8eAh.png)

Comment: [Images of plaintext are not appropriate on StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3784008). Please copy and paste any plaintext into your question.

Comment: "It still wasn't upgraded" is not useful diagnostic information. If you ran `bundle update actionview` then explain what happened when you ran that.

Comment: @anothermh, when I ran bundle update actionview, nokogiri, builder,  crass, loofah, minitest got upgraded. After that I ran "bundle exec bundle-audit update && bundle exec bundle-audit" to check whether "actionview vulnerabilities" exist or not, but vulnerabilities still exist.

Comment: ActionView is bundled with and versioned in lockstep with Rails. You don't update actionview. You update the Rails gem.

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked by updating the Rails gem on the Gemfile to

```
gem 'rails', ' 6.0.2.2'
```

And then running

```
bundle update rails
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question on its own. You should add an note specifically in answer to the actual question, which is about `ActionView` (the actual answer being that ActionView is always required to be in sync with your rails version and the only way to upgrade is to upgrade rails)